# ListView adding item issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I call this peice of code on my form shown event.

It simply adds  a new ListViewItem.

But, the item appears to be invisible, as yo ucan see.. and the columns are gone.

[image: uploaded image]

The code is:

```
private void UpdateList()
{
    listPMs.Clear();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, PrivateMessageInfo> PM in frmMain.Instance.PMs)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = "ddd";
        //lvi.SubItems.Add(PM.Value._Subject);
        //lvi.SubItems.Add(PM.Value._Date);
        //lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(PM.Value._Id));

        listPMs.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I commented out my subitems to see if maybe that's teh issue - which is not. The values are correct. However, it's blank.

My ListView is nothing but a details ListView with 4 columns.

Comment: set `listPMs.View = View.Details`?

Comment: Try removing foreach, and see if you get data. IF that is true then your PMs collection is empty... I have tried code without foreach with default settings (just put listview on form) and it shows items, so maybe code for adding never executes?

Comment: how do you call `private void UpdateList()` in your code?